# Show that $\mathcal{E}_t(M)$ is a continuous martingale bounded in $L^2$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $\alpha$ be an adapted process cadlag (right continuous with left limits), such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}E[\alpha_s^2]ds < \infty$ and $B$ a brownian motion. We define $\mathcal{E}_t(M) = \exp \{ M_t - \frac{1}{2}[M_t]\}$ for all $t \ge 0$ where $M = \int \alpha_s dB_s$. Show that $\{\mathcal{E}_t(M); t\ge 0 \}$ is a continuous martingale bounded in $\mathcal{L}^2$

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(\alpha_s^2)<\infty$? Do you have any thoughts on the problem? (E.g.: What about applying Itô's formula?)

Comment: ooops yes it is !